# Using multiple pivot in Oracle to generate month-wise data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, Discount and Orders. The Discount table contains discounts earned by customers for orders placed in the past. Multiple discounts can be earned for the same order number.

Given an input date range, I need to display summarized discounts and the gross order amount both month-wise and quarter-wise in a separate column for each customer, product combination.

Here's a sample of the data and the query I've designed. The query below shows the result I want to achieve.

[Sample Data & Query](https://dbfiddle.uk/D9CvV0f3)

To explain the query: I start by filtering discount data based on the date range in CTE_DISCOUNT. Next, I select the parent orders from the Orders table in CTE_ORDERS. (This step is necessary because there can be orders that didn't earn any discounts, so we want to select only the orders that earned discounts.)

Then, I pivot both the discount and orders data using a double pivot into CTE_P_DISCOUNT and CTE_P_ORDERS. A simple inner join displays the final results.

My question is, will this approach provide better performance, or should I go with conditional aggregation for selecting the month-wise sum of the amount? Is there an entirely different and better way to write this query? Both tables contain millions of records for each month, so performance needs to be a consideration.

Conditional aggregation : `SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(Order_Date, 'YYYYMM') = '202301' THEN Order_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Sum_Order_Amount_202301`

I also need to display an additional row at the end that shows the sub-total for each month and quarter column. Is there a way to calculate this in the same query?

Comment: TO_CHAR(Order_Date, 'YYYYMM') = '202301' is something I'd include in what not to do. The best would be Order_Date >=date '2023-01-01' and Order_Date<add_month(date '2023-01-01',1). For this TO_CHAR(Order_Date, 'YYYYMM')  would prevent Oracle from using an index on Order_date or a partition by order_date. And even worse would be to create a function-based index on TO_CHAR(Order_Date, 'YYYYMM').

Comment: Cust `323245` only has an order on 2 Jan, yet a gross amount appears for them in every month in the example query. Is that correct?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon sorry, I made a mistake while copying the values. It's selecting "o.M_202301" column from orders table. It should select "o.M_202302", "o.M_202303" & so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot the orders using conditional aggregation and `ROLLUP` for the totals, then do the same for the discounts and join:

```sql
WITH order_pivot AS (
  SELECT order_id,
         cust_nbr,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-02-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202301,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-02-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-03-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202302,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-03-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-04-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202303,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-04-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-05-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202304,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-05-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-06-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202305,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-06-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-07-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202306,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-07-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-08-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202307,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-08-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-09-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202308,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-09-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-10-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202309,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-10-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-11-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202310,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-11-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-12-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202311,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-12-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2024-01-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_202312,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-04-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_2023Q1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-04-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-07-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_2023Q2,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-07-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-10-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_2023Q3,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-10-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2024-01-01' THEN gross_amt END) AS gross_2023Q4
  FROM   orders
  WHERE  crt_ts >= DATE '2023-01-01'
  AND    crt_ts <  DATE '2024-01-01'
  GROUP BY ROLLUP(order_id, cust_nbr)
  HAVING GROUPING_ID(order_id, cust_nbr) IN (0,3)
),
discount_pivot AS (
  SELECT order_id,
         cust_nbr,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-02-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202301,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-02-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-03-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202302,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-03-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-04-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202303,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-04-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-05-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202304,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-05-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-06-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202305,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-06-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-07-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202306,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-07-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-08-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202307,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-08-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-09-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202308,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-09-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-10-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202309,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-10-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-11-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202310,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-11-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-12-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202311,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-12-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2024-01-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_202312,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-04-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_2023Q1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-04-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-07-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_2023Q2,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-07-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2023-10-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_2023Q3,
         SUM(CASE WHEN crt_ts >= DATE '2023-10-01' AND crt_ts < DATE '2024-01-01' THEN disc_amt END) AS disc_2023Q4
  FROM   discounts
  WHERE  crt_ts >= DATE '2023-01-01'
  AND    crt_ts <  DATE '2024-01-01'
  GROUP BY ROLLUP(order_id, cust_nbr)
  HAVING GROUPING_ID(order_id, cust_nbr) IN (0,3)
)
SELECT COALESCE(o.order_id, d.order_id) AS order_id,
       COALESCE(o.cust_nbr, d.cust_nbr) AS cust_nbr,
       gross_202301,
       disc_202301,
       gross_202302,
       disc_202302,
       gross_202303,
       disc_202303,
       gross_202304,
       disc_202304,
       gross_202305,
       disc_202305,
       gross_202306,
       disc_202306,
       gross_202307,
       disc_202307,
       gross_202308,
       disc_202308,
       gross_202309,
       disc_202309,
       gross_202310,
       disc_202310,
       gross_202311,
       disc_202311,
       gross_202312,
       disc_202312,
       gross_2023Q1,
       disc_2023Q1,
       gross_2023Q2,
       disc_2023Q2,
       gross_2023Q3,
       disc_2023Q3,
       gross_2023Q4,
       disc_2023Q4
FROM   order_pivot o
       FULL OUTER JOIN discount_pivot d
       ON     (o.order_id = d.order_id OR (o.order_id IS NULL AND d.order_id IS NULL))
          AND (o.cust_nbr = d.cust_nbr OR (o.cust_nbr IS NULL AND d.cust_nbr IS NULL));
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
Create table Discounts(Id, CUST_NBR, Order_Id, DISC_AMT, CRT_TS) AS
Select 4573950502,'199006P',  2126119004,2.3,TO_DATE('01/22/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 4575504719,'199006P',  2126119004,4.3,TO_DATE('01/22/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 4571314726,'54692P',   2117187823,5.4,TO_DATE('02/03/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 4567113906,'49865P',   2109925333,1.2,TO_DATE('03/20/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 4572930136,'98118002P',2097187737,3.2,TO_DATE('04/23/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 4197912027,'183629P',  1863025629,3.8,TO_DATE('05/18/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 4197912026,'183629P',  1863025629,9.4,TO_DATE('05/18/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 4194722333,'37625001P',1862043278,4.2,TO_DATE('06/19/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;
 
Create table Orders(Order_id, Cust_Nbr, Prod_Nbr, Gross_Amt, CRT_TS) AS
Select 2126119004,'199006P','323245',12.32,TO_DATE('01/02/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 2117187823,'54692P','23453',32,TO_DATE('02/01/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 2109925333,'49865P','234235',23,TO_DATE('03/02/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 2097187737,'98118002P','34546',53,TO_DATE('04/23/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 1863025629,'183629P','2435',67,TO_DATE('04/28/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual union all 
Select 1862043278,'37625001P','3255',34,TO_DATE('05/03/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') from dual
```

Outputs:

| ORDER_ID | CUST_NBR | GROSS_202301 | DISC_202301 | GROSS_202302 | DISC_202302 | GROSS_202303 | DISC_202303 | GROSS_202304 | DISC_202304 | GROSS_202305 | DISC_202305 | GROSS_202306 | DISC_202306 | GROSS_202307 | DISC_202307 | GROSS_202308 | DISC_202308 | GROSS_202309 | DISC_202309 | GROSS_202310 | DISC_202310 | GROSS_202311 | DISC_202311 | GROSS_202312 | DISC_202312 | GROSS_2023Q1 | DISC_2023Q1 | GROSS_2023Q2 | DISC_2023Q2 | GROSS_2023Q3 | DISC_2023Q3 | GROSS_2023Q4 | DISC_2023Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1862043278 | 37625001P | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 34 | *null* | *null* | 4.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 34 | 4.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 1863025629 | 183629P | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 67 | *null* | *null* | 13.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 67 | 13.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2097187737 | 98118002P | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 53 | 3.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 53 | 3.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2109925333 | 49865P | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 23 | 1.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 23 | 1.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2117187823 | 54692P | *null* | *null* | 32 | 5.4 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 32 | 5.4 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2126119004 | 199006P | 12.32 | 6.6 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 12.32 | 6.6 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| *null* | *null* | 12.32 | 6.6 | 32 | 5.4 | 23 | 1.2 | 120 | 3.2 | 34 | 13.2 | *null* | 4.2 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 67.32 | 13.2 | 154 | 20.6 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jHN97YD7)

Comment: This looks more cleaner. I was going to opt for conditional aggregation over pivot, I need to run both queries against the actual data set to find out the performance output. Thanks for the "Group By Rollup" suggestion for generating sub-total.